# How can I add a Google Docs URL to my iOS home screen?

Tags: ios, google-docs

I know how to add an http://blahblah url to my iOS Home Screen using Safari.

I can fashion a URL like GoogleDocs://http://blahblah which will take me directly to the Docs app (not Safari).

My question is, how can I create a Home Screen icon for a GoogleDocs://http://blahblah url?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Shortcuts app](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT209055).

If you create a shortcut to `Web` → `Open URLs` you can use your app URL you crafted above to open the correct application.
From there click the ellipsis in the top right-hand corner, give it a name and then select `Add` to Home Screen.